# Returning ordered collection from EntitySetController Get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to order a collection before returning it from my Get method in my EntitySetController, here is my code :

```
[Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Standing> GetStandings()
    {
        //order by points, goalsfor-goalsagainst, goalsfor, teamname
        IQueryable<Standing> standings = db.Standings.Include("Team").Include("Stage");

        var standingsQuery = from s in standings
            let points = (s.Won*3) + (s.Drawn*1)
            select standings.OrderByDescending(p => points)
                .ThenByDescending(g => g.GoalsFor - g.GoalsAgainst)
                .ThenBy(t => t.Team.TeamName);

        return standingsQuery.AsQueryable();

    }
```

But I get the error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<Standing>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Standing>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Do I need a separate method to return an ordered collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Standing> GetStandings()
{
    //order by points, goalsfor-goalsagainst, goalsfor, teamname

    IQueryable<Standing> standings = db.Standings.Include("Team").Include("Stage");

    IOrderedQueryable<Standing> standingsQuery = standings
        .OrderBy(s => s.Won * 3 + s.Drawn * 1)
        .ThenByDescending(s => s.GoalsFor - s.GoalsAgainst)
        .ThenBy(s => s.Team.TeamName);

    return standingsQuery.AsQueryable();
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you are returning an `IQueryable<IOrderedQueryable<Standing>>` instead of `IOrderedQueryable<Standing>`.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change the IOrderedEnumerable to IOrderedQueryable to get it to work